# Passing current class in constructor, inside actionlistener

Tags: java

So I'm trying to pass the current class inside a constructor of an actionlistner

something like **this:**

```
    public ActionListener createTaskListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                CreateTask ct = new CreateTask();
                CreateTaskController ctc = new CreateTaskController(ct, mod.getAssessments(), this); 
                // but it says anonymous actionlistener 
                ctc.loadDataToTaskView();
                ct.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

    }
```

What is the general approach for a problem like this? Or is this just shoddy code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` will point to the anonymous instance of the action listener. If you want to pass the `this` pointer of the enclosing class, use `<enclosingClassName>.this`.

e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    public ActionListener createTaskListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                ...
                CreateTaskController ctc = 
                    new CreateTaskController(ct, mod.getAssessments(), MyClass.this); // <-
                ...
            }

        };

    }
}
```

---

As a side note. `ActionListener` is a functional interface. So you could simplify your code with a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
class MyClass {
    public ActionListener createTaskListener() {
        return ae -> {
            CreateTask ct = new CreateTask();
            CreateTaskController ctc = 
                new CreateTaskController(ct, mod.getAssessments(), MyClass.this);

            ctc.loadDataToTaskView();
            ct.setVisible(true);
        };    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` within an inner class refers to the inner class instance. To refer to the enclosing class instance, you can use `OuterclassName.this`.

For example

```
public ActionListener createTaskListener() {
    return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            CreateTask ct = new CreateTask();
            CreateTaskController ctc = new CreateTaskController(ct, mod.getAssessments(), YourClassName.this);
            // but it says anonymous actionlistener
            ctc.loadDataToTaskView();
            ct.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: why did you vote me down.is my solution not doing the same as the acceptd answer.Is it bcos i asked for vote? and what is wrong with that.Let be objective

Comment: Ok i am sorry.will not repeat it next time

Comment: ok. basically this within an inner class refers to the inner class.So to refer to the outer class you use the OuterclassName.this.That is the best i can explian. i am truely sorry. next time i will accompay my answer with a bit of explainations